# awk to sort two fields:

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to sort `Input.csv` file based on fields `$1 and $5` and generate country wise `A-Z order`.
While doing sort need to consider country name either from $1 or $5 if any of the fields are blank.

Input.csv

```
Country,Amt,Des,Details,Country,Amt,Des,Network,Details
abc,10,03-Apr-14,Aug,abc,10,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
,,,,mno,50,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,22-Jan-07,Aug,abc,10,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
jkl,40,11-Sep-13,Aug,,,,,
,,,,ghi,30,AL,DEF~PQZ,Sep
abc,10,03-Apr-14,Aug,abc,10,MN,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,19-Feb-14,Aug,abc,10,MN,ABC~XYZ,Sep
def,20,02-Jul-13,Aug,,,,,
def,20,02-Aug-13,Aug,,,,,
```

Desired Output.csv

```
Country,Amt,Des,Details,Country,Amt,Des,Network,Details
abc,10,03-Apr-14,Aug,abc,10,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,22-Jan-07,Aug,abc,10,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,03-Apr-14,Aug,abc,10,MN,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,19-Feb-14,Aug,abc,10,MN,ABC~XYZ,Sep
def,20,02-Jul-13,Aug,,,,,
def,20,02-Aug-13,Aug,,,,,
,,,,ghi,30,AL,DEF~PQZ,Sep
jkl,40,11-Sep-13,Aug,,,,,
,,,,mno,50,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
```

I have tried below command but not getting desired output. Please suggest..

```
head -1 Input.csv > Output.csv;  sort -t, -k1,1 -k5,5 <(tail -n +2 Input.csv) >> Output.csv
```

Comment: shelter, I have re-checked there is no mistake in the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '{print ($1==""?$5:$1) "\t" $0}' file | sort | cut -f2-

Country,Amt,Des,Details,Country,Amt,Des,Network,Details
abc,10,03-Apr-14,Aug,abc,10,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,03-Apr-14,Aug,abc,10,MN,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,19-Feb-14,Aug,abc,10,MN,ABC~XYZ,Sep
abc,10,22-Jan-07,Aug,abc,10,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
def,20,02-Aug-13,Aug,,,,,
def,20,02-Jul-13,Aug,,,,,
,,,,ghi,30,AL,DEF~PQZ,Sep
jkl,40,11-Sep-13,Aug,,,,,
,,,,mno,50,DL,ABC~XYZ,Sep
```

here the header starting with uppercase and data is lowercase.  If this is not a valid assumption special handling of header required as you did above or better with `awk`

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{print; next} {print ($1==""?$5:$1) "\t" $0 | "sort | cut -f2-"}' file
```

Comment: Thank You , karakfa , actual data will be first letter will start with upper case like Afghanistan , Benin,Cape Verde, Croatia ...Zimbabwe

Comment: Very close but should be `awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1?1:0), ($1==""?$5:$1), $0}' file | sort -k1,2  | cut -f3-` to ensure the header line remains at the top.

Comment: Thank You Ed Morton

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? (Omitted first line)

```
cat file_containing_your_lines | awk 'NR != 1'  | sed "s/,/\t/g" | sort -k 1 -k 5 | sed "s/\t/,/g"
```

Comment: Thank You , PejoPhylo sorry above command is not generating the desired output